# Command to find all files in a directory and concat them for a parameter?

Tags: bash, shell, directory

I'm looking for a command which finds all files in a directory using a specific partern, lets say "*.txt" and create a list of parameters from it in BASH.

So if the dir contains:
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
nonsense.c

I need the string "file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt"

I knew there was a BASH/Unix command for this, but I can't remember it :-S. "find" didn't work for me...

Thanks!

Yvan Janssens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want [`ls`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls) and [`xargs`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs).

Comment: xargs - that was the command I was looking for ;-). I was thinking about a thousand commands (not really, but you know it), but I couldn't remember that tiny one...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run a command on files matched by a wildcard, you don't need extra baggage:

```
mycommand *.txt
```

What you remember is probably the `xargs` command. It takes a list of file names on its standard input, and runs a command on these files. For example `echo *.txt | xargs mycommand` is a complicated, and *unreliable*, way of writing `mycommand *.txt`. `xargs` is useful when the list of files that `mycommand` must act on is the output of some other command.

The reason I said `xargs` is unreliable is that it expects its input to be quoted in a peculiar way: all whitespace (not just newlines) separate names, backslashes must be doubled, and `'` and `"` delimit literal strings (in which only backslash and the end quote are special). Since few commands produce output in the `xargs` input format, this limits `xargs`'s usefulness to those rare cases where it is known that file names will not contain any of the special characters.

The `find` command is often used in combination with `xargs`, but this should, and can, be avoided. Instead of <strike>`find ... | xargs mycommand`</strike>, write

```
find ... -exec mycommand {} +
```

Comment: xargs has the `-0` flag to fix most (all?) of those problems.

Comment: @Carl: `xargs -0` fixes the quoting issues, but isn't available everywhere (only GNU and (some?) BSD), and requires the input to be null-separated, which few commands can produce.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is

```
mylist=$(ls *.txt)
```

NOTE: ls reports an error if nothing matches. Errors can be redirected to /dev/null.

For commands other than ls and find, if there are no matches, then wildcard usage usually returns the wildcard as the result; so it is necessary to handle the special case of no matches.

The following sets the variable "list" to all .txt files, or sets it to the empty string if no such files exist. The advantage over ls(1) is that if invokes no external command.

```
list=$(echo *.txt)
if [ "$list" = "*.txt" ] ; then list=""; fi
```

Example usage to run my command, but only if list is not empty:

```
test -n "$list" && my-command $list
```

Now, if your files may have spaces in their names, then an array is better:

```
List=()
let n=0
for x in *.txt
do
    test -e "$x" || exit
    List[n++]="$x"
done
```

Then use the list with

```
test ${#List[@]} -gt 0 && my-command "${List[@]}"
```

or

```
for value in "$List[@]" ; do my-command "$value" ; done
```

All this may be a little different for ksh, yet it would be very similar.

Answer (score 1):

You have asked for one of the most basic features of any Unix shell. It's known as "globbing", for some reason, and it's built-in.

```
$ echo *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "*.txt"
1.txt 2.txt ...
```

Comment: Er, no, if you include the quotes, you will just get `*.txt` printed.

Comment: Oh well, there are way better answers now anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for files in one directory, not in nested directories, you can use a [glob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) argument to your command, which will be interpreted by the shell and produce one argument to your command for each matching filename:

```
$ echo *.txt
file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

If you are looking for files nested arbitrarily deeply within subdirectories, [`find`](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/find1.html) is indeed what you are looking for. You need to pass in the directory you are looking in, and use the `-name` parameter with a quoted glob expression to find the appropriate files (if the glob is not quoted, the shell will try to interpret it, and substitute a list of files matching that name in the current directory, which is not what you want):

```
$ find . -name "*.txt"
file1.txt. file2.txt file3.txt subdir/file.txt
```

If you want to pass these in as arguments to another function, you can use `$()` (which is equivalent to the more familiar backquotes ``` `` ```),

```
echo $(find . -name "*.txt")
```

Or if you are going to get a list that is too long for a single argument list, or need to support spaces in your filename, you can use [`xargs`](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/xargs1.html), which divides its input up into chunks, each of which is small enough to be passed into a command.

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs echo
```

If your filenames contain whitespace, then `xargs` will split them up into two pieces, treating each as a separate argument, which is not what you want. You can avoid this by using the null character, `0`, as the delimiter, with the `-print0` argument to `find` and the `-0` argument to `xargs`.

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 echo
```